# cannot remove or start files/programs

Tags: vb.net

I cannot start or delete files in visual basic 
and every time it runs it says that the distination file:

```
"C:\random\test.exe"
```

it pops up an error and it says: Could not convert String test.exe to the format boolean. (rough translation from swedish), Heres the code:

```
ElseIf t = "run" And Dir(arg1.Text) Then
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(arg1.Text)
ElseIf t = "del" And Dir(arg1.Text) Then
    My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(arg1.Text)
End If
```

its probably something easy to see but im stupid and cant find it ;c

Comment: You need to use msgbox or other methods to show you what the functions you are using return.  Such as, "MsgBox(Dir(My.Application.CommandLineArgs(0)))"  When you do this, you see that the Dir function returns the file name, not a True or False (Boolean).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `FileSystem.Dir()` returns a string and not a boolean, therefore VB.NET can't check your condition (hence the error).

If your goal is to check if a file exists, use `File.exists()` in the `System.IO` namespace.

```
if (File.Exists(arg1.Text))
   'Do a lot of stuff.
```

Comment: Ah you were faster. This is the solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to feed the `If` statement a string representing your directory:

```
If t = "run" And Dir(arg1.Text) Then
    ...
End If
```

Which can be translated to:

```
If (the text is "run") while ("C:\random\test.exe") Then
    ???
End If
```

Which of course is really hard for you to understand and impossible for the compiler to interpret.
You probably want to check if the directory exists, which you can do like so:

```
If t = "run" And File.Exists(arg1.Text) Then
    ...
End If
```

Comment: oh i got it. had to import SystemIO